# OMBD API get a list of movies (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, api, rest

I have a SPA where I would need to show a list of movies from OMDB API (http://omdbapi.com/).

It is pretty easy to send a request for one specific movie (by name, or ID), but how do I get the list of movies, say, all movies of 2015, at least the first 50.

This is the request I send to get one movie

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0499549&plot=short&r=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
        .success(function(response){
            console.log(response);

            $scope.movies = response;
        });
```

Where tt0499549 is the ID.
One options (I don't like it) would be to send 'n' requests and just change and ID +=1, but I believe there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: OMDB is not provide this function. you have to move to other provide if you need list of all movies

Comment: which would it be?

Comment: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Comment: Do one thing. it is not proper way to do but still you can try. Make one php script which is call omdb api with different chars per second and fill your database then make one web service which return movies from your filled database